# Regex: Match everything between two characters, except if also surrounded by a different character

Tags: regex

So, I need a regex that will find everything between two parenthesis, unless there's an apostrophe directly next to both parenthesis, so here, it'd find `str`: `(str)`.

But I don't want it to find `str` in this case: `('str')`, as it's surrounded by `('` `')` rather than `(` `)`.

I've come up with this: `(?<=\(\')(.*?)(?=\'\))` but it does literally the opposite. I was looking for a way to invert it, but I couldn't find one that worked. Am I even on the right track here? I know nothing about regexes, so please excuse my noobishness...

Also, [here](https://regex101.com/r/eblNxu/4)'s a demo of the above regex.

Comment: Maybe `\(([^')]+)\)`? Result in capture group

Comment: What language/tool is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<=\((?!')).*?(?=(?<!')\))
```

To match multiline text, use the appropriate modifier, or `[\w\W]` equivalent:

```
(?<=\((?!'))[\w\W]*?(?=(?<!')\))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eblNxu/5)

**Details**

- `(?<=\((?!'))` - a position right after a `(` that is not followed with `'`
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=(?<!')\))` - a position right before a `)` that is not preceded with `'`

Comment: Excellent, that works perfectly! Thank you very much!